# how to do jdbc connection with sqlserver2000?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

here is the code

```
import java.*;
public class Connect{
     private java.sql.Connection  con = null;
     private final String url = "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://";
     private final String serverName= "localhost";
     private final String portNumber = "1433";
     private final String databaseName= "pubs";
     private final String userName = "user";
     private final String password = "password";
     // Informs the driver to use server a side-cursor, 
     // which permits more than one active statement 
     // on a connection.
     private final String selectMethod = "cursor"; 

     // Constructor
     public Connect(){}

     private String getConnectionUrl(){
          return 

url+serverName+":"+portNumber+";databaseName="+databaseName+";selectMethod="+selectM

ethod+";";
     }

     private java.sql.Connection getConnection(){
          try{
               Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver"); 
               con = 

java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(getConnectionUrl(),userName,password);
               if(con!=null) System.out.println("Connection Successful!");
          }catch(Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
               System.out.println("Error Trace in getConnection() : " + 

e.getMessage());
         }
          return con;
      }

     /*
          Display the driver properties, database details 
     */ 

     public void displayDbProperties(){
          java.sql.DatabaseMetaData dm = null;
          java.sql.ResultSet rs = null;
          try{
               con= this.getConnection();
               if(con!=null){
                    dm = con.getMetaData();
                    System.out.println("Driver Information");
                    System.out.println("\tDriver Name: "+ dm.getDriverName());
                    System.out.println("\tDriver Version: "+ dm.getDriverVersion 

());
                    System.out.println("\nDatabase Information ");
                    System.out.println("\tDatabase Name: "+ 

dm.getDatabaseProductName());
                    System.out.println("\tDatabase Version: "+ 

dm.getDatabaseProductVersion());
                    System.out.println("Avalilable Catalogs ");
                    rs = dm.getCatalogs();
                    while(rs.next()){
                         System.out.println("\tcatalog: "+ rs.getString(1));
                    } 
                    rs.close();
                    rs = null;
                    closeConnection();
               }else System.out.println("Error: No active Connection");
          }catch(Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
          dm=null;
     }     

     private void closeConnection(){
          try{
               if(con!=null)
                    con.close();
               con=null;
          }catch(Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
     }
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
       {
          Connect myDbTest = new Connect();
          myDbTest.displayDbProperties();
       }
}
```

i have installed "c:\program files\microsoft sql server 2000 driver for JDBC"

compiled as:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>javac -classpath "c:\program files\Microsoft
SQL Server 2000 Driver for JDBC\lib\msbase.jar;c:\program files\Microsoft SQL Se
rver 2000 Driver for JDBC\lib\msutil.jar;c:\program files\Microsoft SQL Server 2
000 Driver for JDBC\lib\mssqlserver.jar" Connect.java
```

runned as:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>java -classpath "c:\program files\Microsoft S
QL Server 2000 Driver for JDBC\lib\msbase.jar;c:\program files\Microsoft SQL Ser
ver 2000 Driver for JDBC\lib\msutil.jar;c:\program files\Microsoft SQL Server 20
00 Driver for JDBC\lib\mssqlserver.jar" Connect
```

i get the following output:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Connect
```

i could not find out the cause of this error? how to solve this?

Comment: Did you happen to notice any compilation errors? Does `Connect.class` exist?

Comment: @Brain Roach no i didn't get any compilation error. how to check in sqlserver 2000 the tcp/ip connection is enabled r not?

Comment: This has nothing to do with sql server. `java` is not finding your compiled class `Connect.class` - you haven't even gotten to the point where your program is running.

Comment: @Brain Roach but when i run the program as javac Connect.java it compiles without error and when i run as "java Connect" without classpath it gives a "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserverdriver". what to do?

Answer (score 1):

The current directory is not part of the CLASSPATH by default.  You have to make sure that the path to Connect.class is part of the CLASSPATH.  Add ".;" to the start of your CLASSPATH  and try again.

Start with the basics:

1. Create a folder that is NOT anywhere near where you installed your JDK; call it c:/projects/JDBC
2. Create folders names /src and /classes in your c:/projects/JDBC.  Create a file called Connect.java in the c:/project/JDBC/src folder and copy the source code below into it.
3. Compile Connect.java by typing `javac -d classes Connect.java` at the prompt in a command shell.  If you don't get a Connect.class file in the c:/projects/JDBC/classes folder, you're doing it wrong.
4. Run the program by typing `java -classpath .;classes Connect`.  You should see this output in the shell: You can run a main program.  Now start worrying about JDBC." in the command shell.  If you get that to work, then start adding in JDBC code.

   ```
   public class Connect {

       public static void main(String [] args) {
           System.out.println("You can run a main program.  Now start worrying about JDBC.");
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Connect.class is in the current directory - you should run:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>java -classpath ".;c:\program files\Microsoft SQL 
Server 2000 Driver for JDBC\lib\msbase.jar;c:\program files\Microsoft SQL Server 2000 
Driver for JDBC\lib\msutil.jar;c:\program files\Microsoft SQL Server 2000 Driver for 
JDBC\lib\mssqlserver.jar" Connect
```

This will add the current directory to the class path and allow Java to find the `Connect` class

Comment: how to find whether the sqlserver is running r not?

Comment: i am using sqlserver 2000. it is running. but when i "telnet 1433" it issue cannot open connection to host. what may be the problem

Comment: This has nothing to so with sqlserver - your class isn't even running.

Answer (score 0):

Extract mssqlserver.jar using winzip and import below mention files only in DB connect java file.

```
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.*;
import microsoft.sql.*;
```

now ,simply run java program by calling,

```
java MainclassName
```